# Existence and regularity for fractional elliptic problem with gradient term: $ (-\Delta)^s u + v\cdot \nabla u = 0$ with $v \in \dot H^s$

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, elliptic-pde

Let us consider the problem
$$    (-\Delta)^s u +  v\cdot \nabla u = 0 \quad \text{ in } \mathbb R^n, $$
where $s \in (0,1)$, $(-\Delta)^s$ is the fractional Laplace operator and
$v:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ satisfies $$\|v\|_{\dot H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)}^2:=\iint\frac{|u(x)-u(y)|^2}{|x-y|^{n+2s}}\,dx\,dy < +\infty$$

> **Question.** Where can I find a result on existence, uniqueness and regularity for its solutions? In particular, I'm interested in the
> case $n=2$.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps techniques from the theory of pseudodifferential operators might be of help here? I have a relatively brief acquittance with the subject, but share in hope that it will be of some help to you. You can find more details in e.g. Michael E. Taylor *Partial Differential Equations part 3*, chapters 13.8 and 14.4.

If I understand correctly the symbol of the differential operator in question is:
$$
p(x,\xi)=-|\xi|^{2s}+(\xi,v(x))
$$
where $(\cdot,\cdot)$ stands for the inner product on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. If $s\in(\frac{1}{2},1)$ then $2s>1$. By the regularity assumption on $v$, you can then use the Sobolev embedding theorem to obtain $C^{r}_{*}$-estimates on $v$, and then
$$
|D_{\xi}^{\alpha}p(x,\xi)|\leq C_{1}\langle\xi\rangle^{2s-|\alpha|}
\\\|D_{\xi}^{\alpha}p(\cdot,\xi)\|_{C^{r}_{*}}\leq C_{2}\langle\xi\rangle^{2s-|\alpha|}
$$
for some constants $C_{1},C_{2}>0$. The only nontrivial case seems to be when $|\alpha|=1$, as the $(\xi,v(x))$ term falls under further differentiations by $D_{\xi}$. Then, if again I understand correctly, the existence and regularity results in Chapter 14.4 of Taylor's book seem to apply.

Comment: Thank you. What do you mean by $C^r_\ast$-estimate? Could you add some details on what is the existence and regularity result in Chapter 14.4 of Taylor's book?